# access a variable value inside a src tag in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I need to return data from the laravel controller to show up on my view.
Following is the controller method that i am using to achieve it. I couldnt get the '$imagepath' variable value inside the src and due to this i am unable to load the image in my view. I am a beginner to laravel. Please help thanks in advance.

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()){
        $output="";
        $orderItems=DB::table('orderItem')->where ('order_id','=', $request->orderId)->get();
        if($orderItems){
            foreach ($orderItems as $key=>$orderItem){
                $spare=Spares::find($orderItem->spare_id);
                $imagepath=$spare->imagePath;
                $output.='<tr>'.
                    '<td>'.$spare->description.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$spare->description.'</td>'.

                    '<td>

                     //here i need to set the src of the image

                        <img style="width: 50px;height: 50px;"
                       src="{{asset(\'images/spares/\').\'/\'.$imagepath}}">

                    </td>'.

                    '<td>
                         <a class=" btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalReview"  >Add Review </a>
                    </td>' .


                    '</tr>';
            }

            return response($output);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
src="{{asset("images/spares/{$imagepath}")}}">
```

Comment: oh. i mean it in blade template view.

Comment: i need to pass this data from controller file to the blade via response. I need this src value to be defined in the controller not the blade

Comment: @hEShaN Without blade you can always do: `<img src="{{ asset('images/spares/' . $imagepath) }}">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img style="width: 50px;height: 50px;" src="<?= asset('images/spares/'{$imagepath}) ?>" >
```

Is the type of code you want. You need to just use PHP directly, not blade. Blade is only interpreted when the template rendering engine is loading a file that ends in `.blade.php` (or `.blade`?). Since this is just returning a string directly from the controller to the client, it won't be parsed through anything.

However big warning: **DO NOT DO THIS**. Put your views into view files and return them instead of returning things directly from the controller. There is no reason for this and you (as you are experiencing now) are only making things harder on yourself.

**Updated snippet**:

```
<img style="width: 50px;height: 50px;" src="' . asset('images/spares/'{$imagepath}) . '" >
```

Comment: Then you're going to need to provide the exact error you are receiving and the output on the frontend. The code provided should be exactly what you need considering all provided information.

Comment: Yup, that's right. See, one more example of this bad setup making things harder for people. When you have this level of cognitive overhead to figure something so simple out, you are clearly doing things wrong. Thanks for pointing that out Sanzeeb.